# IFrame visibility and display difference

Tags: jquery, html, css

I understand that element will still take space in the layout if the visibility property is set to hidden ,and element will not take space if the display property is set to none.

And I also believe that the visibility and display properties also mean more than just the difference about the spaces for iframe element. For example, for a file uploader, we use hidden iframe as the target of the request to stop the page to refresh. This iframe needs to be set to visibility:hidden ranther than display:none, otherwise the iframe will not be able to receive the response from server. **Can anyone explain the reason behind it.**

Also, I have seen people set both visibility:hidden and display:none to a hidden iframe, **is there a reason of doing that?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**simple**

`visibility:hidden` keeps the place in the page as if it is there - while `display none` shows you the page as if the control is Not there